# Where to save larger module content/settings?

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm creating blocks in modules and wish to have the block body (content) editable by admins. I'm using `hook_block_configure` and `hook_block_save` to accomplish this. Where is a good place to store the block body when edited by the admin (`variable` is apparently not suitable for larger values like this)?

I was thinking of just creating a custom table in `hook_schema` but that seems a lot for just one or two rows of data. Plus I would be doing this for several modules that need to provide blocks but also have their content editable by the admin. That's why it would be nice if there was a general storage table like `variable` but for larger values.

What would be a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [Nodeblock](https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock)?

There is not a general storage table like `variable` for larger values.

I would consider creating a content type; using the nodes from that content type to programmatically create the blocks, using taxonomy to get finer control if necessary; then admins can just edit the block content like they would a node.

Comment: Thanks for the great ideas! I don't have enough reputation to upvote just yet.